# Angular: Is there a way to bind boolean value to presence of CSS class?

Tags: angular

I can use ngClass to apply a CSS class based on the value of a boolean.  However, can I do the opposite?  Is it possible to change the value of a boolean based on the existence of a CSS class?  Looking around, I cannot find a way to do this in Angular templates.

For context, I'm using `routerLinkActive` to apply a class if the link is active.  What I *actually* need to do is set a boolean value if the link is active.

Comment: Any specific reason for doing this?

Comment: By 'link is active' do you mean if a component is displayed? What would the final purpose be?

Comment: You can check the current route using the `Router` class, and just check the value in your .ts file

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera I have a sidenav with categories, and links belonging to those categories.  I expand or collapse the category based on a boolean value.  Essentially, I am trying to have the category automatically expanded on page load if the current link is within that category.

Comment: @SebastianG I mean the [router link](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links) is active, my above comment gets more into what my rationale is.

Comment: @user184994 I considered doing this, but I'm curious if it can be done in the template, as I imagine the logic would be neater there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `routerLinkActive` directive actually has an `isActive` property you can use.

For example, if we have the following links:

```
<a routerLink="/one" routerLinkActive="active" #one="routerLinkActive">One</a>

<a routerLink="/two" routerLinkActive="active" #two="routerLinkActive">Two</a>
```

Here, i've added a reference on each link to their `routerLinkActive` directive, using the `#name="routerLinkActive"` syntax. As such, we can now reference the `isActive` property like so:

```
<span *ngIf="one.isActive">ONE IS ACTIVE</span>
<span *ngIf="two.isActive">TWO IS ACTIVE</span>
```

Here it's being used to pass a boolean to `*ngIf`, but you can use it anywhere you'd like access to that boolean property.

**[Here is a Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k4zygf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**